# Doctrine form element + zf3 error mensaje “No object manager was set”

Tags: php, formularios, doctrine2, zend

Estoy utilizando Doctrine para crear un DoctrineModule\Form\Elemen\ObjectSelect en mis formularios. Pero al llamarlo de la vista me muestra este error: 'No object manager was set' ("No se ha establecido ningún gestor de objetos"). Me baso en la guía de [DoctrineModule](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/form-element.md) . Llevo un tiempo buscando, pero no puedo encontrar lo que está mal. El código:

El forumlario:

```
<?php
//.....
use DoctrineModule\Persistence\ObjectManagerAwareInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Zend\Form\Form;

class SubRubroForm extends Form implements ObjectManagerAwareInterface
{
    private $value_submit;
    private $objectManager;

    public function __construct($value_submit)
    {
        $this->value_submit=$value_submit;
        // Define form name
        parent::__construct('SubRubro-form');

        // Set POST method for this form
        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
        $this->addElements();
        $this->addInputFilter();
        $this->init();            
    }

    public function init()
    {
        $this->add([
            'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
            'name' => 'rubro',
            'options' => [
                'object_manager' => $this->getObjectManager(),
                'target_class'   => 'Rubros\Entity\Rubro',
                'property'       => 'nombre',
            ],
        ]);
    }
// ... add others elements addElements(){} ....
// ... inputfilters ....
// ... set and get ObjectManager() interface methods...

}
```

La vista:

```
<h3>vista</h3>
<?php echo $this->form()->openTag($form);?>

<?php echo $this->formElement($form->get('rubro'));?>

<?php echo $this->formElement($form->get('submit'));?>
<?php echo $this->form()->closeTag();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Agregandole el init de la clase padre Elements carga correctamente el ObjectManager

class SubRubroForm extends Form implements ObjectManagerAwareInterface
    {
        private $value_submit;
        private $objectManager;

```
    public function __construct($value_submit)
    {
        $this->value_submit=$value_submit;
        // Define form name
        parent::__construct('SubRubro-form');

        // Set POST method for this form
        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
        $this->addElements();
        $this->addInputFilter();
        $this->init();            
    }

    public function init()
    {
        $this->add([
            'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
            'name' => 'rubro',
            'options' => [
                'object_manager' => $this->getObjectManager(),
                'target_class'   => 'Rubros\Entity\Rubro',
                'property'       => 'nombre',
            ],
        ]);
        parent::init();
    }
// ... add others elements addElements(){} ....
// ... inputfilters ....
// ... set and get ObjectManager() interface methods...
```